# How to detect when USB device is being connected/disconnected?

Tags: delphi, usb, device, device-driver

I don't feel comfortable harnessing USB device with Delphi and have a next to nothing  knowledge of the details of writing device driver (though I've come accross some when learning assembly with GoASM).

The device could be either an usb modem or an usb printer.

What I need is a direction to go and sample code adressing the topic.

Comment: try this http://delphiheaven.blogspot.com/2007/03/detect-if-usb-device-is-connected-or.html

Comment: @PresleyDias: Can you migrate your comment as an anwser and elaborate a little so that I can accept it?

Comment: @PresleyDias, but the post from your link is about USB device connect/disconnect notification. I think this question is about "Is certain USB device connected ?"

Comment: @TLama: That's why I asked for an elaboration. I suspect doing an on demand `USBRegister` (RegisterDeviceNotification...) and corresponding cleaning code where appropriate would do. Hint for refactoring the code are welcome.

Comment: If you know some characteristic of your device, you can enumerate USB bus using plain WinAPI (no driver code required) and look for your device in the list of connected devices. I did it, unfortunately my code is too long to be sent as an answer.

Comment: @Serg: That's promising! Maybe the subject of another post. What are those device characteristics?

Comment: @menjaraz for example, for USB drives a combination of 'Manufacture', 'Model Number' and 'Serial Number' characteristics uniquely identifies USB drive, and Windows uses that to remember previously inserted USB flash drives. You can obtain these characteristics programmatically.

Comment: @Serg: Aahh, I see. I recall now that I handled such detail in configuring Linux to recognize a USB modem.

Comment: @menjaraz, I can see the accepted answer, so it seems that you found what you've asked, but please update the question to `How to detect when USB device is being connected/disconnected ?` to correspond to the answer. If you were asking for `Is certain USB device connected ?` then the answer is not the right one. The problem is that if you would have the USB device already connected and start the application with that code, you won't get the device information because it reacts only on newly connected devices, not to those which were already connected at your application start.

Comment: @Serg: Seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163225/744588) does similar things to what you've done in Linux. doesn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was taken from [detect if usb device is connected](http://delphiheaven.blogspot.com/2007/03/detect-if-usb-device-is-connected-or.html)

```
 unit U_Usb;

 interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Forms;

type

PDevBroadcastHdr = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record
dbch_size: DWORD;
dbch_devicetype: DWORD;
dbch_reserved: DWORD;
end;

PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface = ^DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
 DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE = record
 dbcc_size: DWORD;
 dbcc_devicetype: DWORD;
 dbcc_reserved: DWORD;
  dbcc_classguid: TGUID;
  dbcc_name: short;
 end;

const
  GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE: TGUID = '{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}';
  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = $8000; // system detected a new device
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = $8004; // device is gone
  DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = $00000005; // device interface class

type

 TComponentUSB = class(TComponent)
   private
   FWindowHandle: HWND;
   FOnUSBArrival: TNotifyEvent;
   FOnUSBRemove: TNotifyEvent;
   procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
   function USBRegister: Boolean;
   protected
   procedure WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage); dynamic;
  public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnUSBArrival: TNotifyEvent read FOnUSBArrival write FOnUSBArrival;
    property OnUSBRemove: TNotifyEvent read FOnUSBRemove write FOnUSBRemove;
  end;

  implementation

constructor TComponentUSB.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
   begin
     inherited Create(AOwner);
     FWindowHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
     USBRegister;
   end;

   destructor TComponentUSB.Destroy;
    begin
   DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle);
    inherited Destroy;
   end;

 procedure TComponentUSB.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
     begin
     if (Msg.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE) then
      begin
      try
      WMDeviceChange(Msg);
    except
  Application.HandleException(Self);
   end;
   end
  else
     Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWindowHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
   end;

  procedure TComponentUSB.WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage);
   var
   devType: Integer;
     Datos: PDevBroadcastHdr;
   begin
    if (Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) or (Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE) then
    begin
  Datos := PDevBroadcastHdr(Msg.lParam);
    devType := Datos^.dbch_devicetype;
     if devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE then
    begin // USB Device
     if Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then
     begin
      if Assigned(FOnUSBArrival) then
       FOnUSBArrival(Self);
       end
        else
      begin
     if Assigned(FOnUSBRemove) then
      FOnUSBRemove(Self);
   end;
  end;
   end;
  end;

  function TComponentUSB.USBRegister: Boolean;
    var
      dbi: DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
       Size: Integer;
     r: Pointer;
      begin
     Result := False;
     Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
      ZeroMemory(@dbi, Size);
      dbi.dbcc_size := Size;
      dbi.dbcc_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
     dbi.dbcc_reserved := 0;
     dbi.dbcc_classguid := GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;
     dbi.dbcc_name := 0;

     r := RegisterDeviceNotification(FWindowHandle, @dbi,
      DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE
     );
      if Assigned(r) then Result := True;
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: @Thank you! This will serve as a good start and I can see clearly now the direction to go.

Comment: Ok, thats Good, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use some **shell script** to do so.
when device is connected command **lsusb** shows this and removes from list after the device gets disconnected.
So in your shell script you need to find the difference between old list and current list.
Finally you need to run this script as a **cron job**, which checks in frequent interval.

Regards,
Barun Parichha

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thank you for answering. It is valuable indeed but doesn't apply to the case: detecting usb using Delphi in an Windows environment.