# Get HID Device data only from my delphi application

Tags: delphi

I have 2 keyboards attached via usb. I want that my application to receive input only from one of them. I tried to use the TJvHidDeviceController i sucesefully get a handle to the device but i can't get any data.

Is it possible to prevent other applications to receive input from the second keyboard ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i am using a custom made hid device the problem is more complicated but i gave an simple example because the device acts like a keyboard to send some data ;)

Comment: Sounds to me like a barcode scanner possibly?

Comment: nope it's something like this http://yveslebrac.blogspot.com/2008/10/cheapest-dual-trace-scope-in-galaxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for your set-up to not load a device driver for the keyboard you want to listen to? If it is, you could try this method:

- Use [QueryDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to list *all* devices on your computer. You can either search the vendor and device ID in the list if you know them, or build a list before and after you plug in the second keyboard and see which item(s) appear on the list.
- Use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `\\?\` prefix to connect to this device and read/write raw data from it.

Comment: but if the device driver is not loaded can i still read data from it ?

Comment: It's required that you not load a device driver on the device or CreateFile will throw an error to the likes of 'file is already exclusively opened by another process'.

Comment: Hid devices are automatically reconized i have no ideea how i can stop the driver from beeing loaded...

Comment: Please try writing the QueryDosDevice/CreateFile first, there's a chance it will work even without changes to the driver.

Comment: even if it will work what makes you think that i won't receive input in other applications ?

Comment: I've been working with this before: http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=351346 and I noticed it also registers itself as a HID device, using the default driver, but doesn't perform mouse or keyboard events by itself. It comes with a DLL that performs well so I'm not sure what low-level calls it uses. The website you post above has a broken link to the zip with the DLL, so I can't check how it would work.