# installing components of the single unit type

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, installation

My question is how to use unit components like following in our projects.
I installed the following component but i cant to use it anymore.
All of things that i do is : 1- create a package 2- add unit to package 3- with right click on package name in its palette i choose build and after that in the next step i install that 4- next i go to component menu and i choose install component and than by choosing unit and exist package in the next page i add package name and click on finish.
It sounds that all of things is good but i cant able to call that and it not appears in tool pallete after installing.

Basically i always have problem with installing and using components like this...

```
 unit U_Usb;

 interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Forms;

type

PDevBroadcastHdr = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record
dbch_size: DWORD;
dbch_devicetype: DWORD;
dbch_reserved: DWORD;
end;

PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface = ^DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
 DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE = record
 dbcc_size: DWORD;
 dbcc_devicetype: DWORD;
 dbcc_reserved: DWORD;
  dbcc_classguid: TGUID;
  dbcc_name: short;
 end;

const
  GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE: TGUID = '{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}';
  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = $8000; // system detected a new device
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = $8004; // device is gone
  DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = $00000005; // device interface class

type

 TComponentUSB = class(TComponent)
   private
   FWindowHandle: HWND;
   FOnUSBArrival: TNotifyEvent;
   FOnUSBRemove: TNotifyEvent;
   procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
   function USBRegister: Boolean;
   protected
   procedure WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage); dynamic;
  public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnUSBArrival: TNotifyEvent read FOnUSBArrival write FOnUSBArrival;
    property OnUSBRemove: TNotifyEvent read FOnUSBRemove write FOnUSBRemove;
  end;

  implementation

constructor TComponentUSB.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
   begin
     inherited Create(AOwner);
     FWindowHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
     USBRegister;
   end;

   destructor TComponentUSB.Destroy;
    begin
   DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle);
    inherited Destroy;
   end;

 procedure TComponentUSB.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
     begin
     if (Msg.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE) then
      begin
      try
      WMDeviceChange(Msg);
    except
  Application.HandleException(Self);
   end;
   end
  else
     Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWindowHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
   end;

  procedure TComponentUSB.WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage);
   var
   devType: Integer;
     Datos: PDevBroadcastHdr;
   begin
    if (Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) or (Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE) then
    begin
  Datos := PDevBroadcastHdr(Msg.lParam);
    devType := Datos^.dbch_devicetype;
     if devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE then
    begin // USB Device
     if Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then
     begin
      if Assigned(FOnUSBArrival) then
       FOnUSBArrival(Self);
       end
        else
      begin
     if Assigned(FOnUSBRemove) then
      FOnUSBRemove(Self);
   end;
  end;
   end;
  end;

  function TComponentUSB.USBRegister: Boolean;
    var
      dbi: DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
       Size: Integer;
     r: Pointer;
      begin
     Result := False;
     Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
      ZeroMemory(@dbi, Size);
      dbi.dbcc_size := Size;
      dbi.dbcc_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
     dbi.dbcc_reserved := 0;
     dbi.dbcc_classguid := GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;
     dbi.dbcc_name := 0;

     r := RegisterDeviceNotification(FWindowHandle, @dbi,
      DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE
     );
      if Assigned(r) then Result := True;
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: I don't see your `Register` procedure anywhere. That's a requirement to publish components. FWIW, installing components has nothing to do with the unit level. You could have 10 components in a single unit. But you need a `Register` procedure which calls `RegisterComponents` to actually tell the IDE what you want it to do. Otherwise, all you're doing is compiling code.

Comment: I am not familiar with the things that you want me . What procedure i must to add and where i must to assign it?

Comment: @M.MARAMI: If this is the code for an existing component, I assume that there is a second unit that is meant to register your component. It should have a Register procedure. Is that so? If not, [here is how to write a component and register it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Component_Writer%27s_Guide_Index).

Comment: Why are you asking a question here rather than reading the documentation?

Comment: @ David Heffernan: I am sorry. I know that this is very simple for you but believe me that i even did not know must to registered an unit than i research about it.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge: Thank you for taking time. there is not other units but other things i get the above unit from here:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846202/how-to-detect-when-usb-device-is-being-connected-disconnected)
now i need to know my assume is right or not . Is this a component that we should to register or is a normal unit 

that we only must to add to projects?

Comment: Very well I figure outed what i must to do. Can i want from you for begin register this component? By seeing that i can more easily learn this ...

Comment: You would have known that if you'd read the documentation. Simple question. Why won't you read documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit you have does not have a `Register` procedure. This is a requirement to be able to install components into the IDE.

When you install a package, any unit where a `Register` procedure is found in the interface will call this `Register` procedure when the package is "installed". Within there, you then call [`RegisterComponents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.RegisterComponents) to actually install the component(s) into the IDE.

It should look something like this:

```
...

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('My Components', [TComponentUSB]);
end;

...
```

Keep in mind that the `Register` procedure doesn't necessarily need to be in the same unit. Normal design of packages with many components is to have a single unit in the design-time package which has the only `Register` procedure. The rest of the units with the actual components would then presumably be part of a separate run-time package which the design-time package requires.

Also, you can have many components in a single unit. Only those which are in your call to `RegisterComponents` will be installed into your IDE.

Don't forget to also include the location of this unit in the Library Path of your IDE.